# Picking random color from array list

Tags: c#, random, arraylist

So, I am trying to make a function that makes a certain label a random color from a list of colors. This is my code right now:

```
ArrayList colors = new ArrayList();
colors.Add(Color.Black);
Random rColor = new Random();
var randomColor = rColor.Next(0, colors.Count);

colorTextLabel.ForeColor = randomColor;
```

but it just returns an error at the last line of the code saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Color'"

How is this done?

Comment: Oops sorry that was the wrong variable... But still the same error.

Comment: Just a small suggestion - if you are going to be selecting a lot of random colours quickly you need to move the `Random rColor = new Random();` declaration to a class-level variable to prevent non-random values being generated.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`, it is not really used for modern programming very often. A `List<Color>` would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the item at the random index, currently you are trying to assign an int to a Color:

```
colorTextLabel.ForeColor = (Color)colors[randomColor];
```

And do not ever use `ArrayList` while you can use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Comment: That just bring back error "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.Drawing.Color' is a non-nullable value type)"

Comment: I forgot that Color was a struct. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var colours =
    typeof(System.Drawing.Color)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .ToArray();

colorTextLabel.ForeColor =
    System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colours[rColour.Next(0, colours.Length)]);
```

Comment: suppose some color i don't want , so how to put in except condition

Comment: @naweez - before the `.Select` do a `.Where(x => x.Name != "Blue")`.

Comment: @Enigmativety's  if color more then 30 then it will be quit difficult to write in in where condition. For what could be ulterative solutions.

Comment: @naweez - Use `.Contains(...)`.